# angular-schema-form default, hidden values

Tags: angularjs, forms, angular-schema-form

I want to build a (section of a) form which produces the following output:

```
{
  ...
  offers: {
     context: "http://schema.org",
     minPrice: 3
  }
  ...
}
```

The catch is, `context` should always be present - the only field the user gets to manipulate is `minPrice`. Immediately, a hidden field with a value comes to mind. So here's the schema definition:

```
$scope.schema = {
  ...
  offers: {
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
      minPrice: {
        type: 'number'
      }
    }
  }
  ...
};
```

And here the form definition:

```
$scope.form = [
  ...
  {
    key: 'offers',
    type: 'fieldset',
    items: [
      {
        key: 'offers.minPrice',
        type: 'number'
      },
      {
        key: 'offers.context',
        type: 'hidden',
        default: 'http://schema.org'
      }
    ]
  }
  ...
];
```

However, observing the generated model it's obvious the entry `context` is not present. I have successfully used a combination of `type: 'hidden'` and `default` with a `tabarray`, but I just can't get it right with an `object`. I am using version `0.8.13` of `angular-schema-forms` - the latest at the time of this writing.

I'd appreciate any insights, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must include context and it's default value within the schema in that version.

I expect that your issue relates to a bug which *should* have been fixed in the alphas for v1.0.0

It should work with:

**Schema**

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "offers": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "minPrice": {
          "type": "number"
        },
        "context": {
          "type": "string",
          "default": "http://schema.org"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Form**

```json
[
  {
    "type": "fieldset",
    "items": [
      {
        "key": "offers.minPrice",
        "type":"number"
      },
      {
        "key": "offers.context",
        "type": "hidden",
        "notitle": true
      }
    ]
  }
]
```